# Enable form select validation after re-enabling it with jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, disabled-input

Using jQuery Validation. How can I make sure jQuery validates an input that was initially disabled, but then re-enabled based on other form input?

This seems like it would be somewhat common, but I can't seem to track down an answer.  I have an initial form that contains a disabled select dropdown.  Once the user enters some other information in the form, the select dropdown is enabled.  When I submit the form, it doesn't seem to be validating the "required" select dropdown that was initially disabled.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your example code? Sounds like this is an issue with event delegation: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Where is your code?  Secondly, the jQuery Validate plugin automatically enables/disables validation in this situation, so without your code, we cannot answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery validation plugin will do that automatically. Check the following example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            foo: {
                required: true
            },
            bar: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
    
    $('#enable').click(function(){
     $('#bar').attr('disabled', false);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="bar" id="bar" disabled />
    <br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="enable">Enable It</a>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Mayank.  Your example key'd me in that I was using the default, out-of-the-box, validate() method from the jQuery Validation home page.  This example didn't include the specific "rules" section.  Although it works for the simple cases, the home page example method didn't work for my page.  All I did was add the "rules" to the validate() and it worked.  Many thanks.